# How to upload files using codeigniter hmvc

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please help! I was using codeigniter 3 mvc and my code worked just fine. Then I moved to hmvc and my uploads no longer function. Below is my code:

```
class Home extends MY_Controller
{ 
  function __construct()
 {

parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('User_m', 'user');
$this->load->library('upload');

}



public function register()

{

$data['services'] = $this->user->get_service_list();
$data['page_class'] = 'register-page';
$data['title'] = 'Registration';
$data['content_view'] = 'Home/register_v';
$this->template->login_template($data);

}



public function apply()

{

 $directoryname = $this->input->post('company').'/documents';

 if (!is_dir('customer_documents/'.$directoryname)) 
  {
   mkdir('./customer_documents/' . $this->input->post('name_of_org').'/documents', 0777, TRUE);

  }

      //Field Rules

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('company', 'Company/', 'trim|required|min_length[6]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Physical Address', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('tel', 'Tel', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('postal_address', 'Postal Address', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact_name', 'Contact Name', 'trim|required|min_length[6]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact_number', 'Contact Number', 'trim|required|min_length[6]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('position', 'Position', 'trim|required|min_length[6]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules( 'email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|min_length[7]');


          $name_array = array();
          $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['size']);

          foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value)

          for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++)

{

                  $_FILES['userfile']['name']=$value['name'][$s];
                  $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $value['type'][$s];
                  $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
                  $_FILES['userfile']['error']       = $value['error'][$s];
                  $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $value['size'][$s];

                  $config = [

                    'upload_path'             => './customer_documents/'.$directoryname,
                    'allowed_types'         => 'gif|jpg|png|pdf',
                    'max_size'              => '1000000',
                    'overwrite'               => FALSE,
                    'remove_spaces'         => TRUE,
                    'encrypt_name'       => FALSE
              ];
                  $this->upload->initialize($config);
                  $this->upload->do_upload();
                  $file_data = $this->upload->data();
                  $name_array[] = $file_data['file_name'];
 }




        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE && !$this->upload->do_upload()) 

{


            $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
            $data['services'] = $this->customer->get_service_list();
            //Load Template
            $data['page_class'] = 'register-page';
            $data['title'] = 'Registration';
            $data['content_view'] = 'Home/register_v';
            $this->template->login_template($data);
          }

          else

         {

           $names= implode(',', $name_array);

    $data  = array(
      'name_of_org'             => $this->input->post('name_of_org'),
      'address'                   => $this->input->post('address'),
      'tel'                       => $this->input->post('tel'),
      'postal_address'          => $this->input->post('postal_address'),
      'contact_name'              => $this->input->post('contact_name'),
      'contact_number'          => $this->input->post('contact_number'),
      'role'                      => 'admin',
      'position'                  => $this->input->post('position'),
      'email'                       => $this->input->post('email'),
      'userfile'                  => $names,
      'service'                   => $this->input->post('service_id'),


    );
    //Insert User
    $this->user->register($data);


        //isset Message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'You have successfully submitted your registration.');

        //Redirect
        redirect('Home/register');

  }
}
```

Model:

```
class User_m extends CI_MODEL{
 function __construct()
 {

  parent::__construct();
  $this->table = 'users';

}



function register($data)
{
  $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
 }
}
```

When I use the above code to upload files using mvc it works perfectly well but when I transfered it to hmvc it just post other form fields to the database without files yet also creating directory without uploading any files. What might be the problem? Anyone with a solution for this I am stuck. Please help!

Comment: Maybe not solution, but just in case try with `if (!is_dir('./customer_documents/'.$directoryname))`. Notice `./` at beginning.

Comment: @Tpojka thanks but after I made a few changes to the code now I manage to insert into the database but no files are being uploaded into the folder.

Comment: Try with absolute path `(!is_dir(FCPATH.'customer_documents/'.$directoryname))` and fix that in all places accordingly.

Comment: Also `CI_MODEL` should be `CI_Model`.

Comment: Thanks @Tpojka it works

Answer (score 0):

Try with absolute path

```
(!is_dir(FCPATH.'customer_documents/'.$directoryname))
```

and fix that in all places accordingly.

Also `CI_MODEL` should be `CI_Model`